# Regex to check user login doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex

User login must contain only Latin and Russian letters, digits 0-9 and some symbols like dot and others. I would like to use regular expression for check and tried different variants but no one works.

```
errors["error-name"] = '';
var nameRegex = '[a-zA-Z0-9А-Яа-я.+~_-!?*]/i';

if(!values['name'].match(nameRegex)) {
      errors["error-name"] += "Incorrect login<br>";
    }
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Not only, this regex won't match 1 Russian letter. Also, the leading regex delimiter is absent. Try `var nameRegex = '/[-A-Z0-9А-ЯЁ.+~_!?*]/i';`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew in this case,  login even though it contains only latin letters is not correct

Comment: So, what are your requirements? You have not said there must be at least 1 Latin and at least 1 Russian letter.

Comment: Login can containt latin letters or/and russian letters or/and numbers and different symbols like dot and ~ and others.

Comment: So, there must be at least one number and at least one Latin/Russian letter, right?

Comment: Actually, no. I mean, login may contain digits or may not, and may contain only Russian letters and no one Latin letter, and may contain only Latin letter and no one Russian letter and so on. In reg ex I would like to give just list all possible letters, digits and symbols. And If login will contain some symbol which is not in list, it will fail the check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match all Russian letters, just `[А-Яа-я]` range is not enough. You need to also add the letter `[ёЁ]` to the range since it is not inside that one.

Besides, the unescaped hyphen between literal symbols inside a character class creates a range, and it should be better put at the start or end of the character class.

To add restrictions like *there must be at least N of something*, you need to use anchored lookaheads.

```
var nameRegex = /^(?=[^A-ZА-ЯЁ]*[A-ZА-ЯЁ])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])[-A-Z0-9А-ЯЁ.+~_!?*]+$/i;
```

Here is [its demo](https://regex101.com/r/hR7qM8/1)

Here, `^` anchors the pattern at the start of the string, `$` anchors it at the end, `(?=[^A-ZА-ЯЁ]*[A-ZА-ЯЁ])` requires at least one letter, and `(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])` requires at least one digit.

Note I removed all lowercase letters since there is a case-insensitive modifier `/i`.

**To only match the symbols from the list**, use a plain `+` quantifier:

```
var nameRegex = /^[-A-Z0-9А-ЯЁ.+~_!?*]+$/i;
                                      ^
```

If you allow an empty string, use `*` instead of `+`.

Comment: Note the demo contains a bit modified regex just for demo purposes (since the input is multiline).

Comment: Well, I've just tried `var nameRegex = '/^[-A-Z0-9А-ЯЁ.+~_!?*]+$/i';` but in this case even simple login like `admin` fails check.

Comment: [It allows the `admin` check](https://regex101.com/r/hR7qM8/2). Is it JavaScript? If yes, you must remove `'`s.

Comment: Yes, it's reg ex for JS check. As I see, I used wrong function `match` for check. If I use `if(!nameRegex.exec(values['name'])) {...}` it works the right way. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Yes, to just check, you need [`RegExp#test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Comment: Should I use `exec` or `test` ?

Comment: Use `exec` when you need to extract multiple submatches. Use `match` to extract one match with submatches, or multple matches. Use `test` when you need to check if a string matches the pattern or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression **lookaheads** -

`/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\wА-Яа-я.+~\-!?*]).+$/`

In the above regexp, first lookahead `(?=.*\d)` check for digits and the next lookahead `(?=.*[\wА-Яа-я.+~\-!?*])` checks for the ASCII and Russian character sets and the special characters.

If you want to add a minimum password length(like say 8), you can do like this - `/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\wА-Яа-я.+~\-!?*]).{8,}$/`

**Note**: For matching Russian letters I have used the range that you have     used in your question. If that's not complete, change the range in the second lookahead.

Comment: This does not match all Russian letters.

Comment: @– Wiktor Stribiżew Maybe. I don't know Russian. I used the range that @Heidel used in the question.

Comment: Actually Ёё is very rare letter and I don't think someone will use it in their login but all may happen.

Comment: For the last years, ё has plucked up reputation :) Ё-мобиль and so on :)

Comment: Actually it's the first time I hear about Ё-мобиль ;)